# Adding an Event in Acumatica B2B Portal customization

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to add an Event to Acumatica B2B catalog through customization and it is looking for business account attached to admin login. 
Is the business account must for customization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associated business account check is done in constructor of the InventoryLineMaint Graph linked to Catalog form (SP700000) page and if not found; exception is raised which is correct by design.

[How to assign a business account to user in acumatica?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685406/how-to-assign-a-business-account-to-user-in-acumatica/) has step by step instructions to customize Catalog form (SP700000) on Acumatica Portal site.