# How to assign a business account to user in acumatica?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am trying to assign an Business account to an user and not able to figure out how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by assigning a business account to a user? Also not clear whether this is a programming question.

Comment: This is not a programming question. I want to know how to assign a business account to an user through acumatica ERP

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "assigning a business account to a user". There is a workgroup and owner field in the screen, maybe this is what you're looking for?

Comment: *This is not a programming question.* Stack Overflow is for programming questions only. See the [help/on-topic] for more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are trying to customize Catalog form (SP700000) on Acumatica Portal site and getting **Your user profile is not associated with any Business Account** message.

Associated business account check is done in constructor of the **InventoryLineMaint** Graph linked to this page and if not found; exception is raised which is correct by design. And that’s the reason you are seeing this message.

To customize this screen using Acumatica Customization Browser, you should create an admin Portal user who is associated with business account.
Allow roles **Customizer** and **Portal Admin** for External User Type. You need to check Guest Role for these two in order to add here.

**Step # 1**

Login to ERP using admin credential, navigate to User Roles screen (SM201005), and check Guest Role for Customizer and Portal Admin roles in order to add them on EP202500.

[image: Step # 1]

**Step # 2**

Now navigate to User Types screen (EP202500), and select External User Type. Modify to allow roles **Customizer** and **Portal Admin** for External User Type.

[image: Step # 2]

**Step # 3**

Now create External user.

Navigate to Customers Screen (AR303000) and select ABARTENDE customer. Go to Contacts tab and open up existing Contact - Kabuk Fadi, Mr. (CR302000) Navigate to User Info tab and setup External user as below.

[image: Step # 3]

**Step # 4**

Now login to Portal site using this user. You should be able to customize page SP700000 via Acumatica Customization Browser.

Comment: It solved my problem to customize portal page customization. Thanks for help

Comment: I have done all these steps and I am still getting insufficient rights error.  You have insufficient rights to access the object (ProjectBrowserMaint).

Comment: JB90, did you ever get this to work?  I have the same result you do.