# Portal customization

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to add customization to the portal in Acumatica 2018 R1 and I am getting the following error while opening the customization project.

[image]

The admin user having all the right to customization and also a Portal admin & Portal User.

are there any settings I am missing?

Comment: You can refer steps mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685406/how-to-assign-a-business-account-to-user-in-acumatica/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is due to access right is not give for for ~/Frames/ProjectBrowser.aspx

I have added entry in portal site map for ~/Frames/ProjectBrowser.aspx and gave access rights. It is working fine